# Tomcat7 not showing its index page

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-server

I have installed tomcat7 on my Ubuntu server, now in browser when I try to open serverip:8080 it shows nothing but a blank white page and nothing at all. I have tried restarting tomcat service, its working fine. I have stopped and started tomcat service separately its still working fine. I don't know what to do with it any more. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Also check urls localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080

Make sure that tomcat is really getting started once you run the startup script. if default page is not coming up, then it means your tomcat has not started yet. Check logs to identify the root cause.

It's linux machine so use below command to check running java processes :

> $ps -ef | grep java

Comment: tomcat is on a remote server, I am trying to access it from my desktop

Comment: you should login to the remote server and then debug it. Check if there is any java process running $ps -ef | grep java

Comment: if you sure that tomcat is running then make sure that you have appropriate url to test it. Also please login and check if default application ROOT is available inside webapps directory

Comment: Yes its available and it has index.html and META-INF Folder in it. Everything is fine.